# Removing relations is not being audited by audited gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, acts-as-audited

I'm using [Associated Audits](https://github.com/collectiveidea/audited/tree/4.2-stable#associated-audits) on a `has_many through` relation with Collective Idea's [audited](https://github.com/collectiveidea/audited) gem. I see `create` audits for the `through` model being added, but I do not see any audits when that relation is removed.

Here are my 3 models. A `Post` can be in multiple `Categories`.

**app/models/post.rb**

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  audited
  has_associated_audits

  has_many :categorizations, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :categories, through: :categorizations
end
```

**app/models/category.rb**

```
class Category < ActiveRecord::Base
  audited
  has_associated_audits

  has_many :categorizations, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :posts, through: :categorizations
end
```

**app/models/categorization.rb**

```
class Categorization < ActiveRecord::Base
  audited
  audited associated_with: :post
  audited associated_with: :category

  belongs_to :category
  belongs_to :post
end
```

My `Post` form has a pile of checkboxes for categorization:

```
<%= f.association :categories, as: :check_boxes, collection: Category.order(:name), label_method: :name, value_method: :id, label: false %>
```

- When I edit an existing `Post` and **check** a box for a `Category`, I **do** see a new audit entry with a `create` value in the audit's action field.
- When I edit an existing `Post` and **uncheck** a box for a `Category`, I **do not** see a new audit entry.
- I do see `destroy` audits for both the `Post` and the `Categorization` auditable_type fields when I delete a `Post`, so that aspect works nicely.

  1. Can audited track those deselections? If so, how?
  2. Is there anything obviously bad/wrong about my audited setup in the models above? There's no `has_many through` documentation to follow, so I guessed a bit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Potentially related to [this Rails issue](https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/7618), I had to swap out my `dependent: :destroy` lines:

**app/models/post.rb**

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  audited
  has_associated_audits

  has_many :categorizations
  has_many :categories, through: :categorizations, dependent: :destroy
end
```

**app/models/category.rb**

```
class Category < ActiveRecord::Base
  audited
  has_associated_audits

  has_many :categorizations
  has_many :posts, through: :categorizations, dependent: :destroy
end
```

With this setup in place, I'm seeing audits for both adding and removing relations.